# Xcode 64-bit simulator graphics glitch

Tags: ios, xcode

**UPDATE:** 
it still does this, not sure why. But Apple did not reject any of my apps created with this problem in xcode.

---

I am not really sure what is going wrong with my 64 bit simulator in Xcode. When ever I try to run my project in either 64-bit iphone or ipad it gives this glitch for the graphics. The wierd thing is that it works perfectly on my iphone 5s. Anyone know what might be causing this. Please note, that this screenshot is from a new sprite kit project(default with spaceships provided by apple) after a fresh install of Xcode(5.1). Any help would be great. Thanks :)

PS. My os is 10.9 mavericks

[image: ios simulator glitch]

Comment: I have occasionally seen similar "glitches" on the simulator.  No idea what causes them.

Comment: If you can generate a reproducible test case in a new user account on your machine, it is probably worth [filing a radar](http://radar.apple.com).

Comment: Thanks for idea, I didn't even think of this :). I'll see what comes of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved by updating OSX 10.9.4 and updating xcode to version 6.

I first tried to just update my OS to 10.9.4. But that did not fix the problem. After the update to Xcode 6, I have not run across this problem once.